# Integral of $\cos^2(2x+1)$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I'm having trouble with how I go about integrating the following equation:
$\int_0^1 \cos^2(2x+1) \,dx,$

I am familiar with the addition formula
$ \cos(x+a)= cos(x)cos(a)-sin(x)sin(a)$ 
However I'm not sure how this works with regards to $\cos^2(x+a)$

My question is, what is the integral of the above function, and how do I work this out?

Comment: Try starting with a trig identity for half-angles.  There is one that expresses \cos^2(2x)\ in terms of cos(x).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Substitue $2x+1=t$, and use the following Lemma.

$\cos^2(t)=\frac{1+\cos 2t}{2}$.

Using this, we get that the value of the integral is $\frac{4-\sin 2 +\sin 6}{8}$.

I think you can find the solution from here.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\int\cos^2x\,dx=\frac12\int\left(\cos 2x+1\right)dx=\frac12\left(\frac12\sin 2x+x\right) +C$$

Now use this after you substitute $\;u:=2x+1\;$ in you integral

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\cos^2(2x+1)\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Use $\cos^2(x)=\frac{\cos(2x)+1}{2}$:

---

$$\int\frac{\cos(2(2x+1))+1}{2}\space\text{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\int\left[\cos(4x+2)+1\right]\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\left[\int\cos(4x+2)\space\text{d}x+\int1\space\text{d}x\right]=\frac{1}{2}\left[\int\cos(4x+2)\space\text{d}x+x\right]=$$

---

Substitute $u=4x+2$ and $\text{d}u=4\space\text{d}x$:

---

$$\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{4}\int\cos(u)\space\text{d}u+x\right]=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{\sin(u)}{4}+x\right]+\text{C}=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{\sin(4x+2)}{4}+x\right]+\text{C}$$